# sql error running JPQL query using the IN operator

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa-2.0

i have the following 2 JPA classes:

```
@Entity
public class AnalysisPolicy {
    private Set rules;
    //stuff omitted
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set getRules() {
        return rules;
    }
}

@Entity
public class AnalysisRule {
    //stuff omitted
}
```

and the following JPQL query:
`select p from AnalysisPolicy p, AnalysisRule r where r.id=:ruleId and r in p.rules`
which accepts a single parameter, ruleId, of type java.util.UUID (thats the class i use as @Id for all my entities).
trying to execute the query i get the following results:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* select
        p 
    from
        AnalysisPolicy p,
        AnalysisRule r 
    where
        r.id=:ruleId 
        and r in p.rules */ select
            analysispo0_.f_id as f1_12_,
            analysispo0_.f_lastmodified as f2_12_,
            analysispo0_.global as global12_ 
        from
            AnalysisPolicy analysispo0_ cross 
        join
            AnalysisRule analysisru1_ cross 
        join
            AnalysisPolicy_AnalysisRule rules2_, AnalysisRule analysisru3_ 
        where
            analysispo0_.f_id=rules2_.AnalysisPolicy_f_id 
            and rules2_.rules_f_id=analysisru3_.f_id 
            and analysisru1_.f_id=? 
            and (
                analysisru1_.f_id in (
                    .
                )
            ) limit ?
[org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
[org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
```

which means my JPQL is accepted by hibernate, but for some reason the SQL it produces is invalid (the "analysisru1_.f_id in (.)" part).

im using hibernate 3.6 and postgresql 9 for the DB.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query is wrong, `IN` cannot be used that way. You should write

```
select p from AnalysisPolicy p, AnalysisRule r 
    where r.id=:ruleId and r in elements(p.rules)
```

or

```
select p from AnalysisPolicy p, AnalysisRule r 
    where r.id=:ruleId and r member of p.rules
```

But the following query perhaps would be the best of all:

```
select p from AnalysisPolicy p join p.rules r where r.id=:ruleId
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much - your suggestion worked (only tried the 1st one so far). could you please elaborate on why there's a difference between your 3 suggestions (what makes the 3rd one best) and why hibernate accepted my obviously wrong query and didnt throw something ? :-)

Comment: @radai: The first two approaches are more verbose and generate extra subquery (see generated SQL). Although modern DB optimizers should be able to eliminate it, the last approach is more clear. Regarding the behaviour of Hibernate - Hibernate has many quirks. Perhaps it could be called a bug, however, the wrong query finally resulted in exception :).

Comment: Hibernate's HQL to SQL translation started out as very basic, and only got given a proper parser in Hibernate 3. It's still possible to write a lot of things in HQL that the parser accepts but still don't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your HQL looks confusing to me. I think you could rewrite it as this:

```
select r.p from AnalysisRule r where r.id=:ruleId
```

It would return all policies which contains a given rule. You may even put a distinct there :-)

Edit: axtavt was quicker and provided a better answer than me. It also seems that we got a similar idea about rewriting the HQL query.